# elasticsearch search after gives current document

Tags: elasticsearch

If I query elsatic with `search_after: [createdAtDate, documentId]` and `sort: ['createdAt': 'asc']` where `createdAtDate` is date of current document and `documentId` id of current documents,I get next document to it (go forward in pagination).

But if I query `search_after: [createdAtDate, documentId]` and `sort: ['createdAt': 'desc']` I get next documents AND current document. I need to get only next docs, because it is search after yeah. 
What I do wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't find anything, so I suppose it is just works that way.